# Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null! - Spring Boot , Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I got this error when inserting data into the sample_category table by the client-side.
This is my controller method.

```
@PostMapping("/request")
    public SampleRequest createRequest(@Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException{

        User user = userRepository.findById(sampleRequest.getUser().getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User Not Found"));

        Category category = categoryRepository.findById(sampleRequest.getCategory().getId())
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFoundException("Category Not Found"));

        sampleRequest.setUser(user);
        sampleRequest.setCategory(category);

        return sampleRequestRepository.save(sampleRequest);

    }
```

And this is the Model class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample_requests")
public class SampleRequest extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Category category;


    private String description;

    private Boolean approved;

    @NotNull
    private Long quantity;
```

// Getters and setters

and this is the client-side request.

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "user": {
        "user" : 7
    },
    "category": {
        "category" : 1
    },
    "description" : "test description",
    "quantity" : "2"
    
}
```

I need to add new sample request.

Comment: the category (and user I think) nested object is missing `id` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you JSON you are not sending `id` in `id` node. That's why user and category object's `id` is null.

And `findById` accept only not null id else throw execption([Ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findById-ID-)). JSON should be like

```
{
    ...
    "user": {
        "id" : 7
    },
    "category": {
        "id" : 1
    }
}
```